# Can I make Windows 10 Mobile apps using Delphi 10 Seattle?

Tags: delphi

I know Delphi 10 Seattle is currently able to make apps for Windows 10, Android, iOS, OS X and Web. Well does Windows 10 mean that I can also make apps for Windows 10 Mobile and/or Windows Universal Apps?

Comment: No, it means Windows 10 32 or 64 bit. Delphi does not support Windows mobile.

Comment: I rolled back your edit, because you entirely changed the question months after it was answered. However, the answer is still the same - Delphi does not support Windows Mobile or Universal. The next version of Delphi will work with the new features of Windows 10 Anniversary using the Desktop Bridge. You'll find the feature matrix for Delphi on the EMBT website; it clearly explains which platforms are supported, and questions such as this belong in the EMBT forums as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Delphi does not support any kind of Windows Mobile or Windows Universal development at this time.  Microsoft is still researching the possibility of [supporting classic Win32 apps in Windows Mobile environments](http://www.windowscentral.com/microsoft-investigating-win32-support-continuum-windows-10-mobile).

Comment: I would add that Delphi can only mimic such "Metro" style applications, but not natively support them, nor can you publish in the Microsoft Store.

Comment: .NET and Win32 apps can be published to the Microsoft Store via "Project Centennial", which basically puts a Universal wrapper on top of them. But that does not guarantee they can run on Windows mobile/universal platforms.

Comment: Hmm. That's pretty cool. Thanks for this answer and comments. I will check it out and then return to this post again later.